# Designing iterators for a Matrix class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, matrix, iterator

I am creating a `Matrix<T>` class. While implementing iterators for it I stumbled upon a design conundrum.

Internally, the matrix holds the data in a `std::vector<T>` (row-major).
One way of iterating through the matrix is by double iterators (nested) (specified by the `row_double` template parameter):

```
for (auto it_i = mat.Begin<row_double>(); it_i < mat.End<row_double>(); ++it_i) {
  for (auto it_j = it_i->Begin(); it_j < it_i->End(); ++it_j) {
    cout << *it_j << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;    
}
```

The first iterator `Matrix<T>::Iterator<row_double>`:

- iterates through the rows of the matrix
- has a `RowProxy` member
- Dereferencing it returns a `RowProxy`.

`RowProxy` returns `std::vector<T>::iterator` iterators via methods like `Begin()` and `End()`.

My idea is for the `RowProxy` to know the beginning of the line and the size of the line (number of matrix columns).

**The problem** is how `RowProxy` holds the beginning of the line reference:

- My first approach was to make the beginning of the line a `std::vector<T>::iterator`.
  The problem is that in Visual Studio the iterator is aware of the vector and there are debug checks for iterator arithmetics. It throws an error when constructing the `ReverseEnd` iterator (for the line before the first line): the beginning of the line is `num_columns` before the `vector` start. <sub>*please note that this has nothing to do with dereferencing (whitch is UB). I can't create the iterator.*</sub>.
- My second approach was to make the beginning of the line a raw pointer `T *`
  The problem here is that `LineProxy` needs to return `std::vector<T>::iterator` (via it's own `Begin` etc.) and I cannot (don't know how to) construct a `std::vector<T>::iterator` from a `T *` in a standard way. (Didn't find any reference specific to `std::vector<T>::iterator`, just iterator concepts. In visual Studio there seems to be a constructor `(T *, std::vector<T> *)`, in gcc a `(T *)`, neither one works in the other compiler).

The solution that I see now is to make my own iterator identical with `std::vector<T>::iterator` but who isn't bound to any `vector` and can be constructed from `T *` and make `RowProxy` return that. But this really seems like reinventing the wheel.

Since this is part of a library (and the code resides in headers), compiler options are out of the question (including macros that control compiler options because they modify the whole behaviour of the program that includes the header, not just the behaviour of the library code). Also the solution must be conforming to the standard. The language is `C++11`.

Comment: Why implement your own matrix classes when you can simply use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). They solved all this a long time ago :)

Comment: @Wilbert Self learning exercise and I intend to use my own implementation in task assignments.

Comment: I don't see how your suggested syntax for a `for` loop is convenient or efficient. Anyhow, since no standard iterator has the behavior of your `Matrix<T>::Iterator<row_double>`, you should design it yourself. I suggest you have a look at the iterator of [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) for ideas. Also look at [std::slice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice).

Comment: `Matrix<T>::Iterator<row_double>` is implemented. The nested iterator returned by `RowProxy` is now just a `std::vector<T>::iterator`

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way to do this as stated above is to use Eigen, it is really a very nice package.  The next simplest thing to do would be to store size information in your class then you have a very nice way of getting a specific element out of your matrix.  Just write an (i,j) operator that returns vector[i + j*rowlength]. Iterators should work well for looping over the whole vector in one loop, not sure how much sense it makes to loop over in two.

Comment: I have that. I have iterators that work in a single loop. I have an `At(i, j)`, and I have `m[i][j]` (via proxy). I want to know best way to deal with the specific problem mentioned..